# How to parse string representation of PHP associative array and convert to JSON

Tags: javascript, php, json, parsing

I have a string containing a PHP associative array like this, stored in a javascript variable:

```
[
    "id" => "1",
    "name" => "Blah",
    "data" => [
        [
            "id" => "25",
            "type" => "email",
            "data" => "admin@example.com",
        ],
        [
            "id" => "32",
            "type" => "url",
            "data" => "http://example.com",
        ],
    ],
]
```

This string is stored in a variable in my JS script. I want to parse this and convert it into JSON format. How would I go about parsing this? I couldn't find anything useful online as every result pertaining to JSON and PHP always gets me answers pertaining to using `json_encode()` with PHP or `JSON.parse()` with JS which is definitely not what I want to do.

I assume I need to do somekind of scanner type loop but I'm not sure how to go about doing this. Ideally sections containing keys are parsed as being JSON objects. This is the kind of output I would expect:

```
{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "Blah",
    "data": [
        {
            "id": "25",
            "type": "email",
            "data": "admin@example.com",
        },
        {
            "id": "32",
            "type": "url",
            "data": "http://example.com",
        },
    ],
}
```

Thanks

Comment: do you mean the code at the top is an actual string, ie `$str = '["id" => "1",...],]'`?

Comment: Yes but the string is in a variable in javascript, not in PHP, so like var str = '["id" => "1",...],]';
As I said, I'm not running PHP here, I'm running JS and just parsing this as pure text.

Comment: basic idea: convert every [ or ] to { or }, unless it is right after "=>" or is the matching closing bracket of it. After this, convery all "=>" to ":", but just wondering, why not store it in JSON in the first place?

Comment: Right, but how would I go about doing this, matching the strings while disregarding whitespace, keeping track of opening/closing brackets, etc. I'm unclear on how to write the algorithm. That's why I'm asking.

Comment: This string seems to be result of `echo var_dum(@smthg);` You have the simple way - change it to `echo json_encode(@smthg);` and the difficult way - learn javasript. although you need just str.replace(regexp, newSubStr|function) and JSON.parse(str);

Comment: No. There's absolutely no PHP code involved here, I just have text and I want to use JS to parse it into a JSON string. The specifics of why/how I'm getting this PHP assoc array are not important.